# How would one use this toString method for private variables via inheritance?

Tags: java, inheritance, tostring

So typically, for toString methods I use, String.format ("%s, %s", variable, variable) and it works perfectly fine.

For a clearer example,

```
public class example1
{
    int number;
    String name;

    public void setup(String names, int numbers) {
        name = names;
        number = numbers;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Name: %s\n Number: %s", name, number);
    }
}
```

And this works perfectly fine. However, I'm running into an issue when it comes to inheritance and private variables. Note the following example.

```
public class example1
{
    int number;
    private String name;

    public void setName(String names) {
        name = names;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class example2 extends example1
{
    public void setUP(int z) {
        number = z;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Name: %s\n Number: %s", getName(), number);
    }
}
```

The number prints fine when using the toString method, however I only get a null for the name. I tried using the method name, but that wont work and I tried using n, but that wont work as well. I'd just like some clarification on how to go about doing this as it would be extremely helpful to know.

**So, this is my main method**

```
public class example3
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        example1 one = new example1();
        one.setName("Uri");
        example2 two = new example2();
        two.setUP(500);

        System.out.println(one.getName());
        System.out.println(two.toString());
    }
}
```

The number in the toString method prints just fine, its just that the name is null.

**Apparent solution**

```
public class example3
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        example1 one = new example1("Uri");
        test2 two = new test2(one.getName());
        two.setUP(500);

        System.out.println(one.getName());
        System.out.println(two.toString());
    }
}
```

This works well, however I'm not sure how elegant this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a constructor:

```
public class example1
{
    private String name;
    int number;

    public example1(String names) {
        name = names;
    }

    public void setName(String names) {
        name = names;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class example2 extends example1
{
    public example2(String names) {
        super(names);
    }

    public void setUP(int z) {
        number = z;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Name: %s\n Number: %s", getName(), number);
    }
}
```

Doeing that, it calls the `example1` constructor which initialize the `name` variable. Now, when calling `getName()` it returns the string passed through the constructor.

Now, in the `main()`:

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
    example1 one = new example1("Uri");// a name is required
    example2 two = new example2("Uri");// a name is required
    two.setUP(500);

    System.out.println(one.getName());
    System.out.println(two.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with `toString()`. You haven't initialized the `name` member of your object, which is why it is printed as null.

I don't see any constructors in your code, so you should probably use the `setName()` method to initialize the name.

```
example2 ex = new example2();
ex.setUp(5);
ex.setName("John");
System.out.println(ex);
```

EDIT :

In the `main` you posted, you create two objects and set the name only in one of them. In the other, the same remains null. `two.toString()` doesn't print the name, since you only set the name in the `one` object.